# Determine PackageReference items programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nuget

My .NET Core 6 project's `.csproj` has this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Foo" Version="1.2.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Bar" Version="4.5.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How can I determine programmatically (at runtime) that the project references the "Foo" and "Bar" nuget packages, and also determine their versions?

I tried, without success:

- `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`
- `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`

(I'm specifically interested in the [`NuGet.CommandLine`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine) package, in case that makes any difference.)

**UPDATE**
I think the problem is the `NuGet.CommandLine` package. I don't think it's loaded into the appdomain. How can I detect it?

Comment: you can't determine package dependency at runtime unless you create a tool that reads your project file and saves part of it in some appSettings or something like this. Package information is a design time item.

Comment: Dude!!! packages are not loaded into app domain. Package is a collection (or 1) of DLLs for a specific software. Based on your target framework 1 dll is picked during compile. Package might have 10 different versions of the DLLs and only 1 is picked by framework to build your code. That DLL is then loaded at runtime and this is now NOT PACKAGE, this is assembly. The package number has no correlation to DLL version, only by documentations. The file version is too - only for visual differentiation. Inside your assembly you can see which DLL was actually used when compile happened. Package != DLL

Comment: package and assembly shouldn't be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the package's `NuGet.CommandLine.nuspec` has this:

```xml
<developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>
```

Which comes [from here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/745617ea6fc239737c80abb424e13faca4249bf1/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/NuGet.CommandLine.csproj#L28).

So it's not included as a runtime dependency, thus not copied into the `bin/Debug/net6.0` directory, thus not loaded into the AppDomain upon app start.